# Best place to start for learning SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

what is the best place to start learning about SQL Server 2005 Integration services?

I'm looking for links for setup and tutorials on how to get started.  I've read I need a toolkit called SSIS designer however I haven't been able to find it on the SQL Server Enterprise ed dvd nor online anywhere.  I did come across some links in various forums but they are now broken.

Comment: You may be locked into 2005 due to commitment, but if you're just trying to learn to get up to speed, look into SQL Server 2008. There have been a lot of improvements made in 2008, so you'll have a bit richer of a toolset to learn on.

Answer (score 4):

What version of SQL Server are you using? If you're using SQL Server 2000, then you're out of luck: SSIS didn't exist back then, and you don't want to know what *did*.

SSIS is sufficiently rich and complicated that I would not recommend a "tutorial". I'm afraid I have to recommend you read a book (and follow the exercises!). The one that taught me was [Microsoft® SQL Server(TM) 2005 Integration Services Step by Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624054).

You want to install Business Intelligence Studio from the SQL Server DVD. That installs Visual Studio if you didn't already have it, and also installs the templates and tools necessary to develop in SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

I've found lots of good info at [SSIS Junkie](http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/) (http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/).

And MS has some interesting [web casts](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/bi.aspx?tab=webcasts&id=42664).

Answer (score 1):

I liked the well written tutorial at http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm
give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get past the basics, this tutorial/example shows how to use looping, variables and expressions to do some cool stuff:  http://www.sqlmag.com/Articles/ArticleID/95385/pg/3/3.html

The example is aimed at administration and monitoring, but can be applied to many things.

Looks like it's subscriber only now, but you can get the source.

In a nutshell, you store servernames is a table, put them in an 'object' variable and then loop through them performing whatever actions you'd like.

Your connection to 'source server' changes based on expressions you define in the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at SQLIS.com, it's a great site written by some SSIS experts. There are a number of blogs, and we have some articles at SQLServerCentral.com, though not sure we have a good "get started" series.

PragmaticWorks does a lot of SSIS and I've started to see some details on their blog about the various tasks.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are working on a Business Intelligence project I suggest the white-papers from [www.SQLBI.com](http://www.SQLBI.com) for reference. If you understand the basic termonology of standard BI practicies, this will present a good set of best practices. It may be a little complex though if you are just starting out.

I have also found the video training provided by vconferenceonline/SSWUG (http://www.vconferenceonline.com/shows/summer09/uvc/sessions.asp?id=2) to be very useful. Not free - but relatively cheap.